# WPF Dynamic DataTemplate: GridView CellTemplate is not null but VisualTree property is null

Tags: wpf, listview, celltemplate

I am trying to set the DataTemplate of my ListView.GridView's CellTemplate dynamically at runtime.
The problem is when I do this, nothing happens. I checked the CellTemplate and it's not null but its VisualTree property is null. 
Any suggestions?

```
GridViewColumn gvc = new GridViewColumn
    {
        Header = col.Label ?? col.Name,
        DisplayMemberBinding = binding                        
    };

DataTemplate cellTemplate = FindDataTemplate(listView, col.CellTemplate);
if (cellTemplate != null)
    gvc.CellTemplate = cellTemplate;

gridView.Columns.Add(gvc);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, when you set the **DisplayMemberBinding**, the **CellTemplate** is ignored. So when using **CellTemplate**, do not set **DisplayMemberBinding**.

http://krishnabhargav.blogspot.com/2009/06/gridviewcolumn-celltemplate-does-not.html